# Effect of transformation on a point.

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

What is the effect of the transformation $$A(x,y)=(0.6x-0.8y, 0.8x+0.6y)\quad ?$$

I understand how transformations work when the variables are not in the same coordinate. I do not understand how I could predict the effect.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix for this transformation is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0.6&-0.8\\
0.8&0.6
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This is an example of [rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

The effect of your transformation is rotating a point around the origin by an angle $\theta$ where $\cos\theta=0.6$.

Comment: why is it cosine, not sine?

Comment: @rrav123: Ah, that's a typo. Fixed. If you use sine, you get $\sin\theta =0.8$.